# Change svg gradient to solid white with a transition?

Tags: html, css, svg

I can't seem to get a transition on an SVG when I hover it.
The svg has a gradient inside ... but I want it to transition to white on hover.
Any ideas?

```
svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  path {
    transition: fill 0.4s ease;
    &:hover {
      fill: $white;
    }
  }
}
```

```
<svg id="Facebook_icon" data-name="Facebook icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="8.713" height="16.779" viewBox="0 0 8.713 16.779">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0.5" x2="0.5" y2="1" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f7d077"/>
        <stop offset="0.112" stop-color="#ffefaa"/>
        <stop offset="0.269" stop-color="#ffdb74"/>
        <stop offset="0.552" stop-color="#dba846"/>
        <stop offset="0.808" stop-color="#dba846"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f4cd6f"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path id="Icon" d="M8.713,2.785H7.134c-1.238,0-1.479.588-1.479,1.451v1.9H8.61L8.225,9.125H5.655v7.653H2.576V9.125H0V6.142H2.576v-2.2A3.594,3.594,0,0,1,6.412,0a21.049,21.049,0,0,1,2.3.117Z" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CSSOM, a gradient is of type <image>, and you can't transition from an <image> to a solid <color>.
What you can do however is to transition from an <image> to an other <image>, so we should have been able to transition between two gradients, but as of this writing it seems no browser supports transitioning between svg gradients and none supports CSS gradients as `fill` value.

What does work however is to transition the `stop-color` values of the `<stop>` elements.
For this to happen only when the `<path>` is hovered, I did change the structure of your svg.

```css
svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
svg stop {
  transition: stop-color 0.4s ease;
}
svg path:hover ~ defs stop {
  stop-color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Facebook_icon" data-name="Facebook icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="8.713" height="16.779" viewBox="0 0 8.713 16.779">
    <path id="Icon" d="M8.713,2.785H7.134c-1.238,0-1.479.588-1.479,1.451v1.9H8.61L8.225,9.125H5.655v7.653H2.576V9.125H0V6.142H2.576v-2.2A3.594,3.594,0,0,1,6.412,0a21.049,21.049,0,0,1,2.3.117Z"
    fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0.5" x2="0.5" y2="1" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f7d077"/>
        <stop offset="0.112" stop-color="#ffefaa"/>
        <stop offset="0.269" stop-color="#ffdb74"/>
        <stop offset="0.552" stop-color="#dba846"/>
        <stop offset="0.808" stop-color="#dba846"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f4cd6f"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>

</svg>
```